# Heated bed is not heating up

Tags: heated-bed, ramps-1.4

Hello I am building a clone of Prusa MK2. So I connected all the connections to the RAMPS 1.4 shield. I used Pronterface successfully to set the temperature of bed, but it did not heat up... So I tested the RAMPS D8 D9 connectors which showed 2 volts and D10 measures 12 volts. I replaced the MOSFETs and now it shows 4 volts. I also tested my heated bed. The + and - terminals measure 2.2-2.3 Ohms, and the multimeter beeps when I test for continuity and measures 0.5 Ohm.

Can someone help me what the issues are?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can you measure a resistance without continuity? A heated bed will have a resistance in the order of 1 to 2-ish Ohms, so that should be okay.

Comment: I have shown you the image. When i test for continuity it measures 0.5 ohm and now it beeps